# Delta-Share :An error occurred while calling o31.load

Tags: databricks, delta-sharing

Testing Databricks Delta-share and got below error.
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o31.load.
: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: deltaSharing. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:679)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSourceV2(DataSource.scala:733)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:248)
at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:232)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: deltaSharing.DefaultSource
at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:471)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$5(DataSource.scala:653)
at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:213)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.$anonfun$lookupDataSource$4(DataSource.scala:653)
at scala.util.Failure.orElse(Try.scala:224)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:653)
... 14 more

Comment: Please provide more information - how do you installed it, configured, the snippet of code that you're using, etc. Having only stacktrace isn't helpful, as it only shows that you're trying to use some unsupported data source, and error says that you didn't add the necessary libraries

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.